# Profile Page 'top tag' badge icon overflowing to next line

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, profile-page

[image]

The bronze/silver/gold badge symbol goes onto the next line if the tag's name is too big.

This is *not* [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) because this *doesn't* happens for a shorter tag:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the browser, OS and versions of both? Also, can you ensure you are not zoomed in/out? Neither I nor Stéphane can repro this.

Comment: @Oded Windows 7 SP1, Google Chrome 45.0.2421.0 dev-m (64-bit). I'm not zoomed in/out.

Comment: Err. A dev release? Gonna say that's not supported

Comment: @Oded What if it exists in the non-dev version? I don't know because I don't have it!

Comment: We can't repro in non-dev versions ;) - thing about beta software... it is known to be incomplete/buggy

Comment: @Oded ok as you say :) I'm not going to install the non-dev version to test this though! Do you have a non-dev version of Chrome you can test this on??

Comment: That's what I said... I did test it on non-dev Chrome (windows 8.1, but still..), as did Stéphane, using a mac.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ no repro on Current version with the long text etc. http://i.stack.imgur.com/gOC2i.png

Comment: @Tim must be Chrome dev's fault then...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I guess so :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that this only displays on the user's own profile page when they look at it, because of the +438 rep number there:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

For anyone else, it the `...` works perfectly. To solve it, visit the rep tab.

Comment: I'm NOT going to visit that rep tab!! I'd rather live with the bug :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ you proud of it? :P I win: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bRn6Q.png

Comment: I had around 2k before... but then I clicked it :( Well done tho :)